# Call to Render Partial not working after MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was calling render partial like this in MVC 1.0:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/views/shared/categories.ascx", ViewData.Model.Categories); %>
```

Now after dropping MVC 2.0 .dll's, I am getting the error:

```
 CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Categories' and no extension method 'Categories' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What changed?

Do I have to update my solution or anything going from mvc 1 to 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3b537c55-0948-4e6a-bf8c-aa1a78878da0&displaylang=en) and download the release notes for MVC2 there is a section on upgrading an ASP.Net MVC 1.0 project to ASP.NET MVC 2.